# Decrease salary using a SQL query

Tags: sql

I am looking for code to decrease employee salary by 15%, but only if the employee has completed a training course before 15-Nov-2012 and started after 5-Feb-2013.

Comment: You need to show more effort. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your question?  What does the data look like?  What have you tried? What results did you get?  Maybe read through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - until you structure your question better, we can't help you.

Comment: probably it should read "and started a NEW course after 5-Feb 2013". How can you complete a training if you started in the future? But why should you decrease his/her salary? so many questions to be cleared

Comment: I wish I could wield that kind of SQL super power and give myself a 15% pay raise instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making lots of assumptions since your question doesn't have much detail. Here is some generic code assuming that everything is in 1 table:

```
Update employees
set salary = salary * .85 
where training_course_completed < '2012-11-15' 
and start_date > '2013-02-05'
;
```